# How can I get my app is going to uninstall from android devices

Tags: android

When i  used my mobile for testing of android application. I used to run application directly from android studio. now the app is not getting uninstalled, if I am trying to uninstall the app so how i can know ?

Comment: uninstall the app with the device itself

Answer (score 0):

After you have ran the app on the phone from *Android Studio* once it will remain installed and you can launch it again directly from the phone without Android Studio, likewise when you want to remove it **just drag move the icon to the trashcan** (or uninstall icon) as you would remove any other app.

I think this is how it is designed to work.

[image: Remove App]

Comment: I hope this is the question which you were asking